Nodde.js Toad-Scheduler not Executing Tasks as Expected in Production Environment
I'm facing an issue with the Toad-Scheduler package in my Node.js application deployed to a production environment cyclic. While tasks run smoothly on localhost, they intermittently fail to execute on schedule in production, leading to irregular scheduling or complete cessation of task execution. I've ensured environment variables are correctly set, checked server logs for errors (none found), and verified server resource limits, but the problem persists. Seeking advice on troubleshooting steps, best practices, or known limitations when deploying Toad-Scheduler in a cloud-based hosting environment. Appreciate any insights or guidance. Thanks!
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { connectDB } from "./config/db";
import { ToadScheduler, SimpleIntervalJob, Task } from 'toad-scheduler'
import Product from "./models/product";
import { automateSheet } from "./controllers/automate-sheet";


dotenv.config();

const app: Express = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const scheduler = new ToadScheduler();


app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Creative Cod Bot Server");
});

connectDB()
  .then(async () => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`⚡️[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });

    const products = await Product.find();
    for (const product of products) {
      const task = new Task(product?.name, async () => {
         await automateSheet(product?._id);
      })
      const job = new SimpleIntervalJob({ seconds: product?.sheetDuration, }, task,{preventOverrun:true,id:product?.name})
      scheduler.addSimpleIntervalJob(job)
    }
  })

